Mobile Opt-In campaign
We want to start sending text messages to new leads inviting them to opt-in.
From what I have researched, this cannot be done in Journey Builder and the recommended way is to use the Mobile Opt-In Message template in MobileConnect.
My question is, how do I connect this template to an automation to send them the message? The automation is already set up: it runs every hour and updates a data extension that already contains the phone number and locale. It also contains a Journey Entry activity that we use to send these Leads through a Journey.
Thank you very much. I appreciate any help in following best practices here.

I want to share a few thoughts here:

We want to start sending text messages to new leads inviting them to opt-in.

Actually, you need to have their consent first (their opt-in) to send a SMS to them. So it will lead to 2 scenarios:

You don't have their consent and you want to invite them opt-in

-> Create a Mobile Opt-In Message template in MobileConnect. Put a guide/ads in-store signage for example, so they can be aware to text the keyword to short/long number to opt-in, and then your leads can receive the welcome SMS you configured in the template. No need an automation here. Everything will be automated.

If you already have their consent (through paper work or something) and they are not in Mobile Connect yet.


... a data extension that already contains the phone number and locale.

-> Then you can create the SMS in Content Builder, then use it in your journey builder where it will have an option that you can configure to send the SMS to them with honor opt-in.

Thanks Duc Le. We do have their consent, but from a Website. We now want their explicit consent via SMS response.
I'll send the initial message from Journey Builder: "If you want to start receiving marketing messages from us, text OPTIN to SHORT CODE". In this first message, I'm subscribing them to an initial keyword I've set up called "PREOPTIN". And the keyword to answer in the message is "OPTIN".
My question is: in the future I want to send messages only to contacts subscribed to this specific Keyword "OPTIN", but NOT to the ones who did not reply.
How can I achieve this?
Thanks a lot

@LucioRipari There is nothing call "Pre Opt-In" in MC so your keywords "PREOPTIN" and "OPTIN" are treated equally as the customers already subscribed in SMS channel. You may want to check the scenario in this question https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/424670/83900 if it fits to your needs

Thank you. That was helpful. My question has come down to this: Is it possible to use keywords for audience segmentation? I tried to do this through Journey Builder by selecting the "Send only to contacts who are currently subscribed" option, but you can't select a specific keyword there. Is this something that should be done by populating a data extension? For example, I want to send a message ONLY to contacts who are subscribed to X keyword. How can I do that? Thanks again for your help.

@LucioRipari Yes, like what I mentioned above these keywords are treated equally as the customers already subscribed in SMS channel so "Send only to contacts who are currently subscribed" option will work with both "PREOPTIN" and "OPTIN". And yes, you need to a DE which is filtered by the specific keyword for that scenario. You can open a new question for that and I would be happy to answer it.

Thanks Duc, I just did: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/424947/132489
