SMS - Enter an SMS journey only after optin to a keyword
Thank you for taking the time to read this. We are using Mobile Connect here for the first time. The use case is to send a series of SMS via a journey as soon as the subscriber subscribes through a form. Then there is a double opt-in process (handled via the page with the queueMO API).
Once the person has double opted-in, it seems that:
The status of the contact changes from opt-in pending to opt-in for the relevant keyword.
From that point, we would like to proceed with sending the first message.
My question: In your opinion, what would be the best way to send the first SMS (after the opt-in) as quickly as possible?
For now, I am thinking of:
Adding an API entry event to the journey (the subscriber enters the journey as soon as they submit the form).
Adding a 1-hour wait activity and then proceeding to a decision split to verify that the user is subscribed.
Again: thank you

I assume that you could find out who is already opted in after you do the queueMO API to send the first of a double option message and then that person send back with a reply message. E.g. they reply with a Yes.
Then now you need to store it in a separate DE so it can be used to compare with the journey DE (DE is used as the journey data entry source). This consent DE should have a field to determine they subscribed. E.g. "Opted-in" field is a Boolean field.
Create an Attribute Group in Contact Builder, so you can link 1 -1 relationship between the journey DE and the consent DE.
The rest part is like what you are thinking. You put a wait activity for a specific duration and use Decision Split activity to verify that the user is subscribed. In the Decision Split activity, it will let you have an option to evaluate with Contact Data which is the attribute group you have created above to define the path. (Send SMS or Not)
